# Is there a way that I can provide a multiple computed value for each row? using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am super new to javascript/jquery. I am having a hard time computing a per row average of each question. adding Q, E, T then divide to 3 = average. I dont know how to resolve this since the error said there are 3 elements with non-unique id

below is the error I encountered.
[Error encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64B8i.png)

HTML Code for Q,E,T and A (Average)

```
<tbody>
                <tr>
                <td style="text-align: left; width: 316px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="0">{!! $row->function_name !!}</td>
                <td style="text-align: left; width: 316px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="0">{!! $row->mfo_desc !!}</td>
                <td style="text-align: left; width: 341px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="0">{!! $row->success_indicator_desc !!}</td>
                <td style="text-align: left; width: 437px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="0">{!! $row->actual_accomplishment_desc !!}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                    <td rowspan="0" style="text-align: center; border-top: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-right: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-bottom: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-image: initial; border-left: none; background: white; padding: 0.6pt;">
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <select name="Q" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="Q" style="width: 50px">
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="0" style="text-align: center; border-top: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-right: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-bottom: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-image: initial; border-left: none; background: white; padding: 0.6pt;">
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <select name="E" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="E" style="width: 50px">
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="0" style="text-align: center; border-top: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-right: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-bottom: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-image: initial; border-left: none; background: white; padding: 0.6pt;">
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <select name="T" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="T" style="width: 50px">
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td rowspan="0" style="text-align: center; border-top: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-right: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-bottom: 1pt solid rgb(171, 171, 171); border-image: initial; border-left: none; background: white; padding: 0.6pt;">
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="A" id="A" style="width: 50px" readonly>
                          <select name="A" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="A" id="A" style="width: 50px" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td style="text-align: center; width: 316px; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: rgb(171, 171, 171);" rowspan="0">{!! $row->remarks !!}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

The  tag is enclosed with @foreach loop

and here is my jquery code to compute the average.

```
$("#Q, #E, #T").change(function(){
    $("#A").val((parseInt($("#Q").val()) + parseInt($("#E").val()) + parseInt($("#T").val())) / 3);
});
```

Apologies for the HTML code. It is the output from roosterjs website. Thanks in advance!

Comment: providing html codes in text instead of image would be good .

Comment: providing full code and running it

Comment: Updating the post... apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to fix is the HTML: there shouldn't be element with the same ID. One way so solve this in a table would be to add the row number to the IDs (Q1, E1, T1, Q2, E2...), but there is a better solution in your case: assign them classes instead of IDs (I omitted the styles for clarity):

```
<tr style="...">
    <td rowspan="0" style="...">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <select name="Q" class="form-control form-control-sm q-value" style="...">
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="0" style="...">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <select name="E" class="form-control form-control-sm e-value"  style="...">
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="0" style="...">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <select name="T" class="form-control form-control-sm t-value" style="...">
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </td>

    <td rowspan="0" style="...">
        <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm a-value" name="A" style="..." readonly>
        </div>
    </td>

    <td style="..." rowspan="0">{!! $row->remarks !!}</td>
</tr>
```

Then, your javascript is for the three clases: when the change event triggers, you must find out to what row the input or select box bellongs to (`$(this).closest('tr')`), and then find the fourt input/select in said row:

```
$(".q-value, .e-value, .t-value").change(function(){
  let currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
  let EValue = parseInt(currentRow.find('.e-value').val());
  let QValue = parseInt(currentRow.find('.q-value').val());
  let TValue = parseInt(currentRow.find('.t-value').val());
  currentRow.find('a-value').val((EValue  + QValue + TValue ) / 3);
});
```

Now edit any row and the corresponding result will be updated.

Notes:

- It looks like the extras select at the last column was a typo. I removed it from the example.
- I know that starting with html/css/js is hard because all the new information, so here is a small tip: I usually put short inline styles in HTML, but for larger or repetitive styles (like this table), it should be better to add then to a stylesheet (an inline stylesheet in the page head will do).
- Also, jQuery make a lot of work easier, but you should know that everything jQuery does, can be done with vanilla Javascript.